# Performing an exclusive scan on a thrust::device_vector of a user-defined struct. Compiler error

Tags: cuda, thrust

I am tinkering with the Thrust library provided with CUDA. I was trying to perform inclusive and exclusive scans on a device vector of a user defined struct. Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/count.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/fill.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/replace.h>
#include <thrust/scan.h>
#include <thrust/sequence.h>
#include <thrust/transform.h>
#include <thrust/version.h>
#include <vector>

struct mystruct
{
  int first; 
  int second;

};


//Overload the + operator for the used defined struct
  __host__ __device__
  mystruct operator + (mystruct a, mystruct b) 

  {
    mystruct  c;
    c.first =a.first +b.first;
    c.second=a.second+b.second;
    return c;
  }



int main(void)
{

  thrust::host_vector<mystruct>   host_vec(5);
  thrust::device_vector<mystruct> dev_vec(5);

  host_vec[0].first=2 ;  host_vec[0].second=2 ;
  host_vec[1].first=2 ;  host_vec[1].second=2 ;
  host_vec[2].first=2 ;  host_vec[2].second=2 ;
  host_vec[3].first=2 ;  host_vec[3].second=2 ;
  host_vec[4].first=2 ;  host_vec[4].second=2 ; 

  thrust::copy(host_vec.begin(), host_vec.end(), dev_vec.begin());//copy to device
  thrust::inclusive_scan(dev_vec.begin(), dev_vec.end(), dev_vec.begin()); //In-place inclusive scan
  //thrust::exclusive_scan(dev_vec.begin(), dev_vec.end(), dev_vec.begin()); //In-place exclusive scan

  std::cout<<"The inclusive scanned mystruct vector is "<<std::endl;//Print the scan
  thrust::copy(dev_vec.begin(),dev_vec.end(),host_vec.begin());//copy back to host
  for (int i = 0; i < host_vec.size(); ++i)//print the scan
  {
    std::cout<< host_vec[i].first<<" "<< host_vec[i].second << std::endl;
  }



return 0;
}
```

The above code which does an inclusive runs perfectly, giving me the desired result.

Now In the above code I have commented out the exclusive scan. 
If I try to run this **in place** of inclusive scan then I get the following compiler error.

```
Desktop: nvcc temp.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/../include/thrust/detail/scan.inl(68): error: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "int" to "mystruct"
          detected during instantiation of "OutputIterator thrust::exclusive_scan(InputIterator, InputIterator, OutputIterator) [with InputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<mystruct>>, OutputIterator=thrust::detail::normal_iterator<thrust::device_ptr<mystruct>>]" 
temp.cu(54): here

1 error detected in the compilation of "/tmp/tmpxft_00003330_00000000-4_temp.cpp1.ii".
```

What should I do? For reference the result for exclusive scan must be

```
0 0
2 2
4 4
6 6
8 8
```

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit - your class doesn't have a constructor, which should also be a device and host function.

Comment: The version of ```exclusive_scan``` you're using implicitly assumes that the initial value of the sum is ```0```.  So if you want to call it like that, you need to give ```mystruct``` a constructor which takes an ```int``` which would initialize both ```first``` and ```second```.

Answer (score 1):

Changing this line

```
  thrust::inclusive_scan(dev_vec.begin(), dev_vec.end(), dev_vec.begin());
```

with

```
  thrust::inclusive_scan(dev_vec.begin(), dev_vec.end(), 
                         dev_vec.begin(), mystruct(), thrust::plus<mystruct>());
```

Otherwise, place a constructor to your struct which accepts an integer value, so the default value in the scan operation may be cast to your struct implicitly.

```
  struct mystruct {
     mystruct(int a) : first(a), second(a) {}
     ...
  };
```